What's the difference between popScope and pushAndRemoveUntil
I'm building a flutter app and I have a main page, but it also has a login and logout page.
So, if you're not logged in, the main page is replaced with login. Should I use pushAndRemoveUntil, so logged in users can't press back into the login page? And vice versa, if they're logged out, should I use pushAndRemoveUntil so you can't back into the login page? I check for session to make sure user logged in, so the main page won't work, but curious what's the best approach. Curious if this is a hammer and scalpel problem, but I'm not sure which is which.

pushAndRemoveUntil  is about pushing a new route and clearing other routes from the navigation stack
popScope the back button press (either from the Android hardware button or the back button in the app bar) to ask for confirmation or prevent the app from popping the current route from the navigation stack.
You can use pushAndRemoveUntil together with popScope to prevent the user from popping the route, because attempting to pop after using pushAndRemoveUntil can result in a black screen.
learn more about pushAndRemoveUntil
learn more about Pop scope
